# passing string to sub.re not working in Python

Tags: python, regex

This is so far what has been my progress with this regex function :

```
import os, re

dpath="/root/tree/def/"

fmatch = re.compile(r'\s+''[\[]+''[A-Z]+''[\]]+')
pmatch = fmatch.match('[FLAC]')

def replace(pmatch,df):
    m = re.sub(fmatch,df)
    print (m)



def regex(dpath):
    for df in os.listdir(dpath):
        replace(pmatch, df)

regex (dpath)
```

First do a for loop and look for files in `(dpath)`, then pass the directory name string to `replace()`. But I am getting missing argument 'string' error :

```
root@debian:~# python regex3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex3.py", line 18, in <module>
    regex (dpath)
  File "regex3.py", line 16, in regex
    replace(pmatch, df)
  File "regex3.py", line 9, in replace
    m = re.sub(fmatch,df)
TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

Comment: `re.sub` takes three arguments, you've given it two.

Comment: `m = re.sub(fmatch,df, pmatch)`

Comment: I've tried what @AvinashRaj has said before, but when I do I get : `File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 179, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: think `pmatch` is not a string..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to replace alls all matches of the RegEx `\s+[\[]+[A-Z]+[\]]+` to `[FLAC]`

Make sure you do the following:

```
def replace(pmatch,df):
    m = fmatch.sub('[FLAC]', df)
    print (m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @martin-konecny 's Example,

I got this that worked.

## Create Files for Example

```bash
# Run this in your Shell/Terminal
touch /tmp/abc.FLAC
touch /tmp/abcd.FLAC
```

## Run Python

```python
import re
import os

dpath = '/tmp/'

fmatch = re.compile(r'.+\.FLAC')
pmatch = fmatch.match('[FLAC]')


def replace(pmatch, df):
    m = fmatch.sub('[REDACTED]', df)
    print(m)


def regex(dpath):
    for df in os.listdir(dpath):
        replace(pmatch, df)


regex(dpath)
```

## Result:

```bash
# ...
# [REDACTED]
# [REDACTED]
# ...
```

Great if you want to run a search and keep a selection of your results secret.